# Shell script to Search and Export to csv file/Excel sheet

Tags: python, performance, bash, shell

I Need to Search "WAM" in below `/var/log/messages` and Export complete time stamp value to Excel sheet / Text document

```
2013-07-09T02:22:18.535639Z user.info WebAppMgr WAM
2013-07-09T02:22:21.817372Z user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.calculator
2013-07-09T02:22:21.818442Z user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.settings
2013-07-09T02:22:22.746751Z user.info WebAppMgr WAM
2013-07-09T02:22:23.846636Z user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.notes
2013-07-09T02:22:24.851727Z user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.firstuse
```

For terminal Output this will work

```
awk '/\ WAM/ {print $1"\t"}' /home/santosh/messages
```

I need in text file / Excel sheet output like

```
WAM 
2013-07-09T02:22:18.535639Z
2013-07-09T02:22:22.746751Z
```

Comment: So you just need to print `WAM` to the file before the list of timestamps? What's wrong with just `echo "WAM" >foo; awk '/\ WAM/ {print $1"\t"}' /home/santosh/messages >>foo`?

Comment: i need to export excel sheet for different data

Comment: For different data than you showed us in the question? Any data in particular, or you want just some data at random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "WAM"}/\<WAM\>/{print $1}' /home/santosh/messages > text.file
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{v="WAM";print v}$NF==v&&$0=$1' yourfile
```

with your example:

```
kent$  echo "2013-07-09T02:22:18.535639Z user.info WebAppMgr WAM
2013-07-09T02:22:21.817372Z user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.calculator
2013-07-09T02:22:21.818442Z user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.settings
2013-07-09T02:22:22.746751Z user.info WebAppMgr WAM
2013-07-09T02:22:23.846636Z user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.notes
2013-07-09T02:22:24.851727Z user.info sam SAM  ^Icom.palm.app.firstuse"|awk 'BEGIN{v="WAM";print v}$NF==v&&$0=$1'
WAM
2013-07-09T02:22:18.535639Z
2013-07-09T02:22:22.746751Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
awk '/\ WAM/ {print $1"\t"}' /home/santosh/messages > ~/testOutput
```

You can always import as a file delimited by tabs in Excel from that.

Answer (score 1):

BASH:

```
grep WAM /var/log/messages | cut -d' ' -f1 > /home/santosh/messages
```

Python:

```
with open('/var/log/messages') as infile, open('/home/santosh/messages', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("WAM\n")
    for line in (line for line in infile if "WAM" in line):
        outfile.write(line.partition(' ')[0]
        outfile.write('\n')
```